# How to securely deploy a Fullstack website on VPS

Tags: vps, cloud-hosting

I have built an application with Frontend: nuxt, Backend: node and Database: postgres. I want to publish this website on a domain that I have.

I am looking for VPS solution to host it, as they are a bit cheaper than other available options like AWS, hostinger...

I tried ubuntu VPS and run my node and nuxt using pm2 and installed postgres on it. Everything was running fine.

But I am a bit skeptical to use VPS in terms of security.

Can you please suggest some best practices to make it secure? what should be made publicly accessible and what not? is it a good solution to start with VPS? Is there any better solution with less initial investment?

Comment: I suggest you search google for: "first steps ubuntu server" and "harden ubuntu server". Pay attention to UFW, fail2ban, certbot. Also, learn about proxying with apache or nginx so that you can block direct access to your backend. Spend sometime trying and avoid hosting sensitive information untill you are confident.

Comment: @EliaquimTchitalacumbi Thanks for your suggestion. Is managed VPS better than unmanaged VPS for my case?

Comment: Managed VPS will allow you to be free from having to worry about most aspects related to servers and concentrate more time on your app and me more peace of mind.